# Find objects without hashcode

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-7, deterministic

I need to make a program to be more deterministic: that is refactor it such that results will less depend on run.

One of possible not-determenistic reason is: usage HashMap/HashSet/etc with keys which uses default Object `hashCode()`.

The point is that default Object's `hashCode()` uses actual reference to the object in memory, that means that each rerun it could be different.

Is there a good way to print out all classes which has no `hashCode()` method redefined and are used by their hash?

The codebase is huge (up to hundred of MB of code), there are a lot of inner classes, interfaces, abstract classes etc. And figuring out which of maps/sets to be of concern is an issue by its own

Comment: You could write Java code which will read all .java files as test files and search for `public int hashCode()`.

Comment: If it's your codebase to work with, suggest using LinkedHashMap/Set in preference to HashMap etc.  These at least iterate in a predictable sequence.

Comment: Take a look at the [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections). I don't know if it fulfils your specific use case, but at least it will be a good first aproximation.

Comment: `Object.hashCode` hasn't used the object's memory address for years, though the docs still mention it. Instead, it uses a pseudorandom number generator. Since the pseudorandom state depends on which objects and on how many objects hashCode is called, this could give rise to nondeterministic behavior.

Comment: It's possible that Intellij's "structural search" can be used for this.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fundamental flaw in your premise “I need to make a program to be more deterministic”. Either, your program is correct or it is broken. If it relies on unspecified properties, it is broken and there is no sense in trying to make it “a bit less broken”. You have to fix the wrong parts.

E.g., relying on the iteration order of a `HashMap` or `HashSet` is always broken, regardless of how you implement the `hashCode()` method. As demonstrated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45575607/2711488), a `HashSet` of the same content can exhibit a different order for its elements, depending on its actual capacity (a function of the set’s history) or actual Java runtime version, despite the contained elements have a [well defined `hashCode()` implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--).

So kludging at the `hashCode()` methods of your classes doesn’t improve your application, you have to fix the parts that are wrongly relying on the returned numbers (and likely relying on other unspecified implementation details).

Comment: I love this! *there is no sense in trying to make it a bit less broken*, should really be stamped on my team-leads face )

Answer (score 2):

There is a flawed assumption in your question: `HashMap` or `HashSet` are not guaranteed to return their items in any particular order, no matter the implementation of `Object::hashCode`. Instead of looking to `hashCode` to provide determinism, if you require iteration in a specific order, you should look at the implmentations of `Map` and `Set` that *do* provide guaranteed iteration order.

One example is `java.util.LinkedHashMap`, which is just like `HashMap`, except that items are guaranteed to return in the order they were put into the map. `java.util.LinkedHashSet` is similar, but as a `Set`. If you require a different order, `java.util.TreeMap` and `java.util.TreeSet` can be constructed with any `Comparator` you want to provide a custom deterministic order to your structure (it uses the natural sorting order by default).

Comment: thanks for reply, replacing all Hash collections with another types will lead to performance degradation and make the results of next version being even more different from the current one. The point is how to figure out the needed cases to be refactored .