# Difference in Java Collection between JDK 6 and JDK8

Tags: java-8, java-7, jdk6

I was wondering if the implementation of java.util.collections has changed between Java 6 and Java 8. 
I have this test that works fine in Java 6 but not in Java 8

```
Set<String> types = new HashSet<String>();
String result;
types.add("BLA");
types.add("TEST");
```

The result in Java 6 : [BLA, TEST]
The result in Java 8 : [TEST, BLA]
I already looked in the documentation and release notes of JDK 7 and JDK 8 but didn't find any difference between JDK 6 and the two others concerning this.
Thanks in advance for the clarifications.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45575607/2711488). It shows that the iteration order can differ even with the same implementation version, depending on the hash set’s history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no reason to expect the `[BLA, TEST]` output in either JDK6 or JDK8, since the Javadoc doesn't promise you the elements of the `HashSet` will be printed according to insertion order (or any order). Different implementations are allowed to produce different order.

If you want to ensure that output in both JDKs, use a `LinkedHashSet`, which maintains insertion order:

```
Set<String> types = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
String result;
types.add("BLA");
types.add("TEST");
System.out.println (types);
```

will print

```
[BLA, TEST]
```

in both versions.

By the way, this output is not guaranteed by the Javadoc either, so it can be considered as an implementation detail that may change in future versions, but's it's less likely to change. The reason for this output is that `AbstractCollection`'s `toString()` (which is the implementation `HashSet` and `LinkedHashSet` use) lists the elements in the order they are returned by the iterator.

> **String java.util.AbstractCollection.toString()**
>
> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements **in the order they are returned by its iterator**, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).

Comment: So, did the hashing logic change between versions?

Comment: @user7 I didn't verify the output in Java 6, but based on the Java 6 output the OP claims, the hashing logic must have changed (either the `hashCode()` implementation of `String` class, or, more likely, the secondary hashing performed by `HashSet`/`HashMap`).

Comment: Ok. On a quick look, seems the internal `hash` utility method logic in HashMap seems to have been changed.

Answer (score 5):

The implementation did change, but who cares? You are dealing with a `HashSet` that documents as having no order to rely-on. So simply printing, is not doing anything, just showing that all elements *are there*.

In java-9 `Set#of` and `Map#of` (the new collections) have no defined order *from run-to-run* for example. No order defined == do not rely on it.